# Windows Disk CleanUp issue

Tags: windows, windows-8, disk-cleanup

I have Windows 8.1. My problem is that Disk CleanUp start automatically and disappear when I move the mouse so I can't do anything with it. Is there a way to disable this program?

Comment: It should only be running if you run it.

Comment: It SHOULD. But it's not

Comment: are you saying that it starts upon System start up? or automatically at some time during the day?

Comment: When system is on but I'm not doing anythig on computer (ex. moving mouse, watching video etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a *scheduled task*.

You can find that scheduled task by

- Right-click on the Start button and choose Control Panel
- Choose "Administrative Tools"
- Choose "Task Scheduler"
- Go to Task Scheduler (Local) -> Task Scheduler Library -> Microsoft -> Windows -> DiskCleanup
- Right-click on "SilentCleanup" and choose "Disable".

It's only meant to run when disk space is running low, so you might want to fix that instead of ignoring the root problem.

I suggest that you don't change any other scheduled tasks, as some of them are useful for the smooth running of your computer.